# Use Android to detect other devices running my app nearby

Tags: android, gps

Is there any API or framework or anything that I can use in my Android app to detect other Android devices nearby that also have my app running on them?

Comment: Why would there be an API written for an app that you're writing?

Comment: Well obviously I didn't mean specifics. I just want to know if an API exists that can detect information about other phones within a specified radius nearby (using GPS I guess). Does this sort of API even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slandau,

The [Bump App API](http://bu.mp/api) is available and has a *somewhat* similar feature implemented.  When two phones "bump" one another it uses their current location to know which two phones bumped.  So, their proximity is calculated to some degree.  You should look into their API and see if you can do something similar.  I don't think there is just a standard API for this as the privacy/security risks should be obvious.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. This is an awesome start. Appreciate it.

Comment: Does BUMP only work if you are on the same network or within bluetooth range?

Comment: No, I've used it with AT&T iPhone users from Verizon on my Droid both on their separate cellular networks.

Comment: Very interesting. Okay cool. I'll see if it's possible using the same technology to recognize a phone further away.

Comment: @WilliamTate, is that BUmpAPi limited only few meters ?
What about the API without internet connection? what is the alternative to Bump API?

Answer (score 1):

Look at what Google Latitude does:

http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/

Comment: +1 that's a really good one too.  i regularly use latitude and i didn't even think about that ><

Comment: Latitude is awesome however, where as Bump can detect a DEVICE near you, I think latitude can only detect a latitude USER near you, and not necessarily find out any info about there device. Ultimately I need to send/receive info from these detected users, and knowing only that they are there, wouldn't be enough. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Latitude can only achieve the latter.

Comment: Yes Google latitude would be one part of your solution. You may have to provide some meta data layer that associates location to a certain device, application, capability, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of "nearby" means inside the same wifi network or within bluetooth range, then be aware that Qualcomm have put together a free SDK and platform to build peer-to-peer application on Android, which works over both Bluetooth and/or Wifi.

http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/alljoyn-p2p

Comment: By "nearby" I'm referring to a user specified # of miles/feet. So I would like to use GPS/Bump to get data on phones.

Comment: i dont know why but alljoyn explanation seems OK. But the code seems very frustating for the beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `Google Nearby` API https://developers.google.com/nearby/.
It uses Wifi, Bluetooth and allows phones to emit ultrasonic sound which is imperceptible to humans to detect NearBy Devices.....